# A heuristic for finding the vector that is maximally distant from a set of vectors

Tags: sets, clustering, euclidean-distance

I have two sets of vectors: `A` and `B`. I want to find the vector `Bi` in set `B` that is maximally distant from the vectors in set `A`, either by average distance or closest distance. I know that I can accomplish this by comparing every vector `Ai` in `A` with every vector `Bi` in `B`, but that will be very costly. It is acceptable for the solution to be approximate. Is there a heuristic algorithm that can solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: Another [related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52222/computing-farthest-pair-of-points-in-d-dimensions) question.

Comment: @PålGD The dimension-space is potentially unlimited. O(nlogn) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer with some ideas.

If you have too many dimensions, you can use the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) to reduce the dimensions while keeping distances approximately the same (some $\epsilon$ away from original distances).

You can find a 3-approximation for the point in $B$ that is farthest away from any point in $A$ (pick any $b' \in B$, then find an $a \in A$ that is farthest away from $b'$, and then pick a $b \in B$ that is farthest away from $a$).  This should be a 3-approximation for the farthest $A$-$B$-points.

However, you want to minimize the point in $B$ farthest away from all of $A$, so maybe you can try to find the centroid $c(A)$ and find the point in $B$ that is farthest away from $c(A)$?  Note that this only works if *most* points in $A$ are *close* to $c(A)$.  You can also try to remove outliers first.

A randomized approach could be to choose e.g. a constant fraction of the points in $A$ and perform the centroid algorithm, and repeat as many times as you see fit.  Or you can choose, say $\log |A|$ many points in $A$ and find the point in $B$ farthest away from this set.  Repeat as many times as you can.

These are all suggestions where we don't know *anything* about $A$ and $B$.  How are they generated?  Do they follow some probability distribution?  If you use the knowledge you have about these sets, you will very likely get better algorithms.

Finally, you can see if you can use a [$k$-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to come up with a better algorithm.